State object is not updating, instead it is showing the default in the database

i'm new to react and I'm trying to update the CategoryId in the state object. In the handleCategoriesChange method, I have attempted to update the state with the option selected from the dropdown with the index. In the database, it is just saving the default value which is 1 but not the option that is chosen. I would appreciate any help thanks.
CreatePost.jsx
 import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Formik, Form, Field, ErrorMessage } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";
import axios from "axios";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { AuthContext } from "../helpers/AuthContext";
 
function CreatePost() {
   const { authState } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const [listOfCategories, setListOfCategories] = useState([]);

  const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = useState(null);
 
   const [initialValues, setInitialValues] = useState({
     title: "",
     post: "",
     ingredients: "",
     image: "",
     categoryId: 1,
   });
 
  let navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!localStorage.getItem("accessToken")) {
      navigate("/login");
    }
    axios.get("http://localhost:3001/categories").then((response) => {
       setListOfCategories(response.data);
      });
 
  

  }, []);
  const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    title: Yup.string().required("You must input a Title!"),
    post: Yup.string().required(),
    ingredients: Yup.string().required(),
    
  });
 


  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    axios
      .post("http://localhost:3001/posts", data,  {
        headers: { accessToken: localStorage.getItem("accessToken") },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        navigate("/");
      });
  }

const updateDropdown = (event) => {
    const index = event.target.selectedIndex;
    setSelectedIndex(index) 
    console.log("The index is: " + index)
    
   };

  return (
    <div className="createPostPage">
      <Formik
        initialValues={initialValues}
        onSubmit={onSubmit}
        validationSchema={validationSchema}
       >
        <Form className="formContainer">
          <label>Title: </label>
          <ErrorMessage name="title" component="span" />
          <Field
            autocomplete="off"
            id="inputCreatePost"
            name="title"
            placeholder="(Ex. Title...)"
          />
          <label>Post: </label>
          <ErrorMessage name="post" component="span" />
          <Field
            autocomplete="off"
            id="inputCreatePost"
            name="post"
            placeholder="(Ex. Post...)"
          />

          <label>ingredients: </label>
          <ErrorMessage name="ingredients" component="span" />
          <Field
            autocomplete="off"
            id="inputCreatePost"
            name="ingredients"
            placeholder="(Ex. ingredients...)"
          />

          <Field as="select" name="categoryId" onChange={updateDropdown}>
            {/* <option value="none">None</option> */}
            {listOfCategories.map((item, index) => (
              <option value={item.category_name} key={index}>
                {item.category_name}
              </option>
            ))}
          </Field>
          {selectedIndex !== null && <p>Selected index: {selectedIndex}</p>}

          <button type="submit"> Create Post</button>
        </Form>
      </Formik>
    </div>
  );
}

export default CreatePost;




You cann't directly update 1 property from object , you have to add the previous object data in setState, for this you have to use spread operator [... Prevstate]
updateProperty function allows updating any property by passing the property name and the new value as arguments. This approach makes the code more flexible and reusable, allowing you to update any property in the initialValues object.
Follow the below code.
const updateProperty = (CategoryId, index) => {
ConstsetInitialValues(prevState => ({
  ...prevState,
 CategoryId : index
}));

};
Hope this answer help you, kindly update the answer,if this worked for you.
Thanks

I have tried that approach, but it is still not updating the category because it is still showing the default value which is 1 in the database and not the option index that is chosen

Have you tried adding the category id with hard code value?

I have added it as a hard-coded value and it shows the id in the database. The state doesn't respond when I pass the index which I have a console log and it shows the index of the selected option. I'm using sequlize.js as well but yh I have tried many things and it still uses the hard coded value and nothing else

Have your index changing when you tried to select from option, have you checked that in console ?

Yh i did this as well I can see the index changing when I select an option and print to the console. I just can't see the value in the database updating. I will add pictures

I noticed categoryId you are using is in lower case, it should be in camel case, could you please use
CategoryId :index

I'm still getting the same result with CategoryId: index, it is still using the default value which is 1

Have you tried this whole things ConstsetInitialValues(prevState => ({
...prevState,
CategoryId : index
}));

I have tried ConstsetInitialValues(prevState => ({ ...prevState, CategoryId : index })); it is still doesn't update the category id in the database just shows 1 as the categoryId
